# Need help with my partitions to move my Ubuntu from HDD to SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, ssd, transfer

Ok so, on my laptop I dual boot windows and Ubuntu. When installing ubuntu I screwed up somewhere and the 50gb I partitioned for data is now unallocated and my Ubuntu only has 18 gbs. Didnt matter for  a while cuz 18gb was ok. Now I started doing some computer heavy coding and  my ubuntu lags like crazy when I'm running my programs. I have a 1TB HDD and a 500GB SSD. my Windows currently is on my SSD and my ubuntu on HDD. What I want to do is split my SSD as 370/465 is still free. And I guess reinstall/move my ubuntu on that partition. I dont know how to go about doing this so some help would be greatly appreciated. My current disk management looks like this.

I mainly want to do this because, correct me if I'm wrong, but moving my ubuntu on SSD would make it faster or atleast lower the lag when I'm working wont it?

[image: Disk Management]

Edit:

Here is the GParted SS, I tried sudo gparted -l but got this error "Could not stat device -l - No such file or directory."
So I screenshotted my gparted.

[image]

Comment: Please boot from Ubuntu and run `sudo gparted -l` then highlight the results and copy them, the come back here, click [edit] and paste them into your question. Please do not use Add Comment as formmating is lost.

Comment: Depends what is causing the lag. Sometime lag is caused by disk operations, sometimes not. Troubleshoot it a bit before you commit to repartitioning.